# pygal charts line up horizontally

Tags: python, charts, alignment, pygal

I am trying to get my pygal.SolidGauge charts to line up in a horizontal line like this: 
[charts in horizontal row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMWic.png)

But I find that by default the charts are stacking up vertically like this:
[charts in vertical row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVqiV.png)

How can I get them to line up horizontally? I am using Python 3.5.1 and here's my code

```
import pygal

def create_chart():
    gauge_chart = pygal.SolidGauge(show_legend=False, inner_radius=0.70, half_pie=False)

    gauge_chart.add('Max ', [{'value': 58, 'max_value': 100}])
    gauge_chart.add('Min ', [{'value': 42, 'max_value': 100}])
    gauge_chart.add('Mean', [{'value': 28, 'max_value': 100}])

    gauge_chart.render_to_png("chart.png")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_chart()
```

Answer (score 1):

most likely the charts are being rendered in `<div>` elements

by default, `<div>` elements have `display: block;`
and will stack vertically

to test, add the following css to the page

```
div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

if correct, the charts will then stack horizontally, assuming the screen is wide enough

if so, remove the test and add a class name to the chart containers, e.g.

*html*

```
<div class="chart"></div>
```

then add css for class

*css*

```
.chart {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This is to generate a PNG file to embed in a PDF, not to render in a HTML. But following your suggestion I tried adding a style to the chart as below  my_style = Style(display='inline-block') and called in the the method like this :  gauge_chart = pygal.SolidGauge(show_legend=False, inner_radius=0.70, half_pie=False, style=my_style) but this hasn't helped...